# Jobs - it is difficult to reach messages

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow-jobs

I think it is a bit difficult to reach messages / previous communication related to jobs.

I suggest adding a link to messages somewhere like here:

[image]

Comment: So what's the feature request?

Comment: To put it in a more clear place, so that it can be accessed easily.

Comment: To be honest, I couldn't find the link, and the only way to access my messages is from the email which I have received!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a link on the right side; the small envelope next to the Developer Story link takes you to your messages.

Comment: I would suggest adding a textual form, as a developer, I generally tend to search the page from the browser :)